# Parse Postgres array to Python list

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

I have loaded some data into a pandas dataframe from a CSV file, exported from Postgres. One of the columns comes from a PostgreSQL array field, and looks like so (note that it is a string enclosing the array):

```
"[
    {"keyOne": "valueOne", "keyTwo": "valueTwo"},
    {"keyOne": "valueOne", "keyTwo": "valueTwo"},
    ...
]"
```

Note: the object keys are all double quoted. However, not all of the values are double quoted, as some were originally boolean.

How can I parse this into a Python list with the following form:

```
[
      {"keyOne": "valueOne", "keyTwo": "valueTwo"},
      {"keyOne": "valueOne", "keyTwo": "valueTwo"},
]
```

Comment: Are all of the quotes double quotes? And, can you post an example of the list you want? (e.g., all elements, in order)

Comment: I updated the question with regards to your questions. Thanks ☺

Comment: Got it. Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085382/python-how-can-i-strip-first-and-last-double-quotes

I'm having trouble getting a field like yours into pandas via read_csv.

Comment: Ok, cool. Will that return a list? I might be able to use df.column.apply(json.loads).

Comment: If you remove the first and last double quotes, you should have a list, yes. The issue with the repeated double quotes is that you have a string - `"[{"` - followed by essentially a variable declaration - `keyOne` - followed by a string - `": "`, etc. Stripping the first and last quotes should be all you need. LMK!